# How to programmatically set selection Highchats master-detail chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have created my own master-detail chart following the Highcharts docs and this example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

Eveything works fine but I would like to add a feature: When the chart is loaded the last 50 data points should automatically be selected in the master chart and thus shown in the detail chart.

I tried to manually trigger the selection event but it did not work out. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you considered using stockCharts instead; https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line ? It makes managing zoom a lot easier. If that is not an option for you, you would need to use the same function as is used for the selection event, and make sure it only uses the last 50 points.

Comment: You would need to do something like this; https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/52b40dg6/12/. This was just a quick and messy way of using the selection event function.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire `selection` event in chart load event and set correct extremes:

```
            chart: {
                ...
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var points = this.series[0].points,
                            xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

                        Highcharts.fireEvent(this, 'selection', {
                            xAxis: [{
                                min: points[points.length - 51].x,
                                max: points[points.length - 1].x
                            }],

                        });
                    },

                    selection: function(event) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xy8qug9h/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load