# How to programatically call Highcharts Selection event

Tags: highcharts

There is a function called setExtremes() which has to be called on either X-Axis or Y-Axis. But I have a requirement where I need to call the chart.events.selection event programmatically.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            selection: function (event) {
                      }
                }
       }
 }
```

Comment: May I ask why do you need to trigger the Selection event programmatically? Please also take a look at this related question, which might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590642/how-to-programmatically-set-selection-highchats-master-detail-chart

Comment: I am trying to implement lazyloading along with a feature where users can save a particular zoom level. I don't want to call setExteme function on both the x and y-axis separately, thus want to fire the selection event

Comment: But how are you gonna pass the coordinates to the selection event?